Boxing a row and diagonal elements of a matrix in two-column
I am trying to box the elements in second row and the diagonal elements as shown in the picture below:

I tried using tikz, nicematrix packages, but nothing is helpful. Since the matrix is spanning two columns in a page and is coming under figure environment, I am not sure how to box the row and diagonal elements. Also the width of the elements in the diagonal are not the same and boxing would obviously result in overlapping. what is the best way to do this in research articles?
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\highlightr}[1]{%
  \ooalign{\hss\makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{red!30}{red!40}{$#1$}}\hss\cr\phantom{$#1$}}%
}
\newcommand{\highlightg}[1]{%
  \ooalign{\hss\makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{green!30}{green!40}{$#1$}}\hss\cr\phantom{$#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!hb]
\footnotesize{
\begin{align}
    \boldsymbol{H} = \left[\begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt}ccccccc} 0 & \highlightr{\frac{p_1s_0t_0}{2}} & \frac{p_1(s_0t_1+s_1t_0)}{2} & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \frac{p_1s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2}\\[5pt]\hdashline\\[0.1cm]
    \frac{p_1s_0t_0}{2} & \highlightg{p_2s_0^2t_0} & \boxed{\frac{2p_2s_0s_1t_0}{2}} & \dots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_0}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0\\[3pt]
    \frac{p_1(s_0t_1+s_1t_0)}{2}  & \frac{2p_2s_0s_1t_0}{2} & p_2(s_0^2t_1+s_1^2t_0) & & \vdots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_1}{2} & \ddots & \vdots\\[3pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\[3pt]
    \vdots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_0}{2} & \dots & \dots & p_2(s_0^2t_{M_h}+\dots+s_{M_w}^2t_0) & & \ddots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2}\\[3pt]
    \vdots & 0 & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_1}{2} & \ddots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\[3pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \ddots & \vdots \\[3pt]
    \frac{p_1s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0 & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2} & \dots & \dots & p_2s_{M_w}^2t_{M_h} 
    \end{array} \right].
\end{align}}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


Please extend your code sniped to complete MWE.. We need to know what you have in your document preamble.

Hi thank you, now it is edited including all the packages required to replicate the MWE

\tikzmark and [remember picture,overlay] work fine in a figure* environment (but [hb] doesn't, only [tp]).  Just make sure everything is in the same float.

Thank you, can you provide the latex code for it?

I wound up using tikzpictures instead of tikzmarks so that I could save all the corners (anchors).  Note that the elements of an array are in \textstyle, not \displaystyle.
It takes two runs to make changes.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\highlightr}[1]{%
  \ooalign{\hss\makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{red!30}{red!40}{$#1$}}\hss\cr\phantom{$#1$}}%
}
\newcommand{\highlightg}[1]{%
  \ooalign{\hss\makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{green!30}{green!40}{$#1$}}\hss\cr\phantom{$#1$}}%
}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[3][]% #1 = node options (optional), #2 - node name, #3 = array element
{\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#2.base)] \node[inner sep=2pt,#1] (#2) {$\textstyle #3$};}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\footnotesize
\begin{align}
    \boldsymbol{H} = \left[\begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt}ccccccc} 0 & \highlightr{\frac{p_1s_0t_0}{2}} & \frac{p_1(s_0t_1+s_1t_0)}{2} & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \frac{p_1s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2}\\[5pt]\hdashline\\[0.1cm]
    \frac{p_1s_0t_0}{2} & \tikzbox{H1}{\highlightg{p_2s_0^2t_0}} & \tikzbox{H2}{\frac{2p_2s_0s_1t_0}{2}} & \dots & \tikzbox{H3}{\frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_0}{2}} & 0 & \dots & 0\\[3pt]
    \frac{p_1(s_0t_1+s_1t_0)}{2}  & \frac{2p_2s_0s_1t_0}{2} & p_2(s_0^2t_1+s_1^2t_0) & & \vdots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_1}{2} & \ddots & \vdots\\[3pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\[3pt]
    \vdots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_0}{2} & \dots & \dots & p_2(s_0^2t_{M_h}+\dots+s_{M_w}^2t_0) & & \ddots & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2}\\[3pt]
    \vdots & 0 & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_1}{2} & \ddots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\[3pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \ddots & \vdots \\[3pt]
    \frac{p_1s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0 & \frac{2p_2s_0s_{M_w}t_{M_h}}{2} & \dots & \dots & \tikzbox{H4}{p_2s_{M_w}^2t_{M_h}}
    \end{array} \right].
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[red] (H2.south west) rectangle (H3.north east);
  \draw[red] (H1.south west) -- (H1.north west) -- (H1.north east) -- (H4.north east) -- (H4.south east) -- (H4.south west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure*}
\end{document}



Below is a toy example. IMO, nicematrix and tikz are the packages you should be after. It shouldn't matter if the nicematrix environment is placed in one- or two-column document, and whether it spans one or two columns. All should work as long as space is available.
The only requirement is you do have to understand some basics of tikz including a few additional packages (links to both tikz and nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    hl/.style = {
        fill=#1,
        draw=none,
        inner xsep=3.5mm,
        inner ysep=3.5mm,
        rounded corners=1.5mm,
    },
    hlrange/.style = {
        fit=(2-6)(3-6),
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        inner ysep=-3pt,
        inner xsep=3pt,
    },
    diag/.style = {
        line width=25pt,
        line cap=round,
        draw=#1,
    },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \boldsymbol{H} =
    \begin{bNiceArray}{c:*6{c}}[cell-space-limits = 9pt, margin]
        \CodeBefore[create-cell-nodes]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[diag=Blue!15] (2-2) -- (3-7);
            \node[hl=Red!20] at (1-2) {};
            \node[hl=green!40] at (2-2) {};
            \node[hlrange=(2-6)(3-6)] {};
            \draw (1-5) circle (3mm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \Body
        1 & 234 & 56 & 789 & 12 & 345 & 6 \\
        \hdottedline
        7 & 890 & 12 & 345 & 67 & 89 & 2 \\
        3 & 456 & 78 & \boxed{900} & 90 & 123 & 4 \\
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


